# create dimmed icon with magick++ (ImageMagick)

Tags: c++, icons, imagemagick, magick++

I’m trying to use ImageMagick for what I believed would be a simple task.
I want to generate a dimmed version of an image/icon at runtime in the application. 
I use the magick++ c plus api.

I have found some commands that give me an ok result when run from the command line.
Converting the commands to the c++ api was a bit challenging, and the result is then not as hoped.

```
// Command example
convert -size 32x32 xc:"#999999" gray32.png
composite -dissolve 50% logo32.png gray32.png dim_logo32.png
```

How would this look in c++?
I came up with this.

```
Magick::Image gray;
gray.size( Magick::Geometry(image.columns(), image.rows()));
gray.read( "xc:#999999");
gray.label( "gray" );

if(gray.isValid()) {
gray.opacity(QuantumRange/2);
image.composite(gray, Magick::Geometry(image.columns(),image.rows()), Magick::DissolveCompositeOp );
```

But the transparency in the picture is lost.

A other suggestion as to make a dimmed image, is to make the full image semi transparent.

```
convert input.png -channel Alpha -evaluate Set 50% output.png
```

This could work. The transparency is kept when I tried this from command line.
Changing this to c++ api confused me a lot.

I ended up with this single line.

```
image.opacity(QuantumRange/ 2);
```

Now the result from this confuses me. The image is semi transparent, but the background that was originally transparent is now magenta.

I was not allowed to post the images, to show the result. :(